# Convert GMT timestamp to local time using Bash and GNU tools

Tags: linux, bash

I am getting results to a log file that contain a line like this:

```
date: Sat, 12 Dec 2020 22:33:34 GMT
```

I want to use only Bash and GNU tools on my Ubuntu Linux box if possible to convert this to my local time "Eastern" or Michigan/Detroit.  It should work even on Daylight Saving Time or if past/before Midnight.  I want the result stored in a variable in a common format such as 2020-12-01 for December 1, 2020.  One variable for the military time, a second for the date would probably be best.  I can calculate the "Sat/Sun/Mon/etc" and probably don't need that anyway.

I would expect the "cut" command could separate out the different fields, but how to deal with GMT?

```
#!/bin/bash

datime="date: Sat, 12 Dec 2020 22:33:34 GMT"

#magic happens

echo dalocaltime is $dalocaltime and dalocaldate is $dalocaldate
```

results:

```
dalocaltime is 14:20:33 and dalocaldate is 2020-01-30
```

Comment: Try `date -d "${datime#* }" '+%R'`, it shouldn't be hard to figure out the rest.

Comment: Indeed this lead me to the answer.  Amazing how I didn't need to use any TZ stuff and it just took the string the way I had it.

Comment: GNU date is indeed an amazing program. `${datime#* }` removes the shortest prefix ending with a space (i.e `date: ` in this case) from `datime`'s value.

Comment: This  one liner  does  timezone conversion:
`TZ=CST6CDT date -d "$(TZ=GMT date -d '2023-05-02 01:03:25.584') "` returns :  
"Mon May  1 20:03:25 CDT 2023"

Answer (score 2):

This works for me, but I can't explain the `${datime#* }` part

```
datime="date: Sat, 12 Dec 2020 22:33:34 GMT"
dalocaltime=$(date -d "${datime#* }" '+%R')
dalocaldate=$(date -d "${datime#* }" '+%Y-%m-%d')
echo dalocaltime is $dalocaltime and dalocaldate is $dalocaldate
```

Comment: That's a [parameter expansion.](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) It trims the text up through the first space.